# Google Summer of Code: web classification dataset

Tags: dataset, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, data-mining, classification

I heard that Google hosted (or will host) a web classification competition and they provided a large (170k+ documents) dataset of web sites that were classified into multiple categories (sports, computers, science, etc.) I tried looking around in their Summer of Code web site for 2009 through 2011, but didn't find anything. Does anybody know where I can get that dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it (although I'm not sure if the data was provided by google): [the ECML/PKDD 2010 Discovery Challenge Data Set](http://datamining.sztaki.hu/?q=en/DiscoveryChallenge) contains 22 training labels (i.e. labels about the content), URLs and hyperlinks, content-based and link-based web spam features, term frequencies and Natural Language Processing features.

Comment: The labels do not include the category. Please refer https://dms.sztaki.hu/node/351