# Available Training Data for Functional Webpage Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, html

I'm working on a project where I need to do both subject & functional classification of webpages, as described in [Web Page Classification: Features and Algorithms](http://www.cse.lehigh.edu/~xiq204/pubs/classification-survey/LU-CSE-07-010.pdf)
 by Qi and Davison.  For example I may want to be able to tell if a particular page is about music, and whether it is a collection (list of links) or topic (data about one specific link from a collection) page.  For subject classification I'm using a subset of the [DMOZ Directory](http://www.dmoz.org/) data to generate a set of training examples by crawling sites that are labeled with a particular topic as positive examples, along with negative examples.

I'm less clear on an approach that will work for functional classification.  Essentially I need a way to find a set of urls that are labeled by type: collection pages, topic pages, etc.  It's probably not feasible to generate a set by hand, and I want to be able to update the classifiers as webpages change on a somewhat regular basis.  Any ideas on areas where I can find labeled data to use for my training set?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question [Google Summer of Code: web classification dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394653/google-summer-of-code-web-classification-dataset)  may be helpful. Specifically, check this link: https://dms.sztaki.hu/en/letoltes/ecmlpkdd-2010-discovery-challenge-data-set